# How to change code variables with Gradle command line arguments

Tags: java, gradle, command-line-arguments

We are students in a high school robotics team. We need to build a robot and then build another "copy" of the same robot (so we have two identical robots). However, there are some differences between the robots. For example, their wheels' friction coefficients are a bit different.

We have a Java class holding the constants of the first robot, and another class holding the constants of the second robot. All other code is identical for both robots.
We have a boolean flag that indicates which constants-set we want to use now (for the first robot or the second one). Currently, we need to change this flag manually in the code, each time we want to deploy the code to one of the robots.

We write our code in Java 12 and build it with Gradle 5.1.1. Is there a way to use command-line arguments with Gradle to change the flag in question?
Say somewhere in the code we have this flag, named `isFirstRobotUsed`:

```java
public static final boolean isFirstRobotUsed = true;
```

Is there an option to build the code like that: `.\gradlew build first` or `.\gradlew build second`,  which will change `isFirstRobotUsed` inside the code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

your  main function :

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.out.println(args);
    boolean firstRobotUsed = Boolean.valueOf(args[0]);
    ...

}
```

your build.gradle

```
run {
    if ( project.hasProperty("isFirstRobotUsed") ) {
        args Eval.me(isFirstRobotUsed)
    }
}
```

your commandline prompt:

```
gradle run  -PisFirstRobotUsed="['true']"
```

Alternatively , use -D JVM system arguments ( like in this link: https://www.lesscoder.com/java/how-to-pass-arguments-to-gradle-run/ ) and you can read system properties using  System.getProperty().